# Correct way of binding click event to list item in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default" id="1">Name1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="2">Name2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="3">Name3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="4">Name4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="5">Name5</li>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(function() {
   $("#sortable1 li").each(function()
   {
        $(this).on("click",make($(this)));
   });

   function make($li)
   {
        alert("hello");
   }
});
```

**fiddle :**

http://jsfiddle.net/gztRq/433/

when i run the fiddle , it will automatically displays the alert for five list items. 
actually i have binded click event for list item so whenever  the list is clicked it needs to call the function.

but why the above "make" function triggered five times before am clicking the list.  after clicking  the list item nothing happened. what is the problem ?

when i write the function code in-line everything works as expected.

**Working code:**

```
 $("#sortable1 li").each(function()
 {
    $(this).on("click",function()
    {
      alert("hello");
    });
 });
```

what is the correct behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$.each()` loop completely and just use:

```
$('#sortable1').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert("Hello"); // Or make($(this)); if you still want that extra function
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gztRq/436/).

Comment: Thanks. i knew that why it was not working in each function. anything wrong in code ?

Comment: @SivaRajini I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: your answer u mentioned remove $.each loop completely. what is the reason ? why we can't bind the click event is  each function ?

Comment: @SivaRajini because there's no need for it. `$('#sortable1').on('click', 'li', ...)` adds a `click` event to all the `li` items contained within `#sortable1`.

Answer (score 3):

You call your function, don't add "(", ")". Just write name function (is reference). And `this`, is already define for the event function.
http://jsfiddle.net/gztRq/437/

```
$(function() {    
   $("#sortable1 li").each(function() {
       $(this).click(make);
   });
   function make() {
        alert("hello "+$(this).text()); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
 $(this).on("click",function(){make($(this))});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gztRq/435/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#sortable1 li").click(function(){
     make($(this));
});
```

Comment: why that one not working in each function ? what is the correct behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$(document).on("click","sortable1 li",function(){

});
```